# How to open a apsx page from SilverLight Application as a modal-dialog?

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can I call an aspx page from a SilverLight application, so that it opens in as a modal dialog and it blocks interaction with the SL application until the dialog is closed?

Thanks

Comment: Did the Invoke showModalDialog answer I gave in your very similar question not solve the problem then?

Comment: Is the aspx page hosted on the same server as the Silverlight application and the silverlight application's host page?

Comment: Yes, same server; but a different app on the same IIS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ChildWindow control and set its content to a WebBrowser control pointing to your page's url but it will work in OOB mode only

Comment: @vc 74 : I managed to do it; but is there a way to make it work without OOB mode?

Comment: It should work also in browser provided that you set WindowLess mode to true (and understand the consequences): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156(VS.95).aspx

Comment: @Francesco: As vc 74 points out WebBrowser is only available OOB however WindowLess mode might basis for an answer of sorts.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I confused the WebBrowser control with Telerik's HtmlPlaceholder (http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/htmlplaceholder.aspx). It's not free but will work inside the browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Html bridge to call a javascript that opens a new window (a "fake window" like you see in many image galleries these days). You could also add a layer on top of your silverlight content to disable interaction (for example with a grid that block any mouse click).
Also with a javascript you can again tell your silverlight app when the "window" is closed.

This will not work OOB of course.